# Is it okay to save the youtube urls of the format http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID in database?

Tags: video, youtube

I want to save a set of youtube video links for my website. I tried looking at http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html and ttp://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html but did not find an answer to my question.

> Is it okay to save the youtube urls of the format www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID in database?

If not, *Suggest some ways that would not break the videos at some point when/if YouTube updates its video urls.*

Comment: Why not just store the VIDEO_ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the video id only, and the URL itself should be constructed. This way you can manipulate the video id however you need. Not to mention that it's less overhead in the database.